# Xamarin forms custom pin clicked

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, google-maps-markers

I'm using https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps this library for map integration in my Xamarin app. In this library we can have custom pins. So I have implemented the custom pin which is having two buttons. But as per my knowledge pin is rendered as a image. Isn't it possible to know which part of pin is clicked without using paid APIs.

Comment: Why dont you simply put Pin as pin then When you click on pin Display those buttons over the Pin (not as an Image) !!

Comment: Did little bit same. When user taps on pin, that pin is getting centred on screen. added a pop-up over screen which is live view and centred also. Now user can interact with buttons in live view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user taps on pin, that pin is getting centred on screen. Added a pop-up over screen which is live view and centred also. Now user can interact with buttons in live view.